# "Sound effect added for awesome", is this correct?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/tMDKeBaLWDw) video, at around 2:45 the following sentence popped up on the screen:

> *sound effect added for awesome.

Is "for awesome" correct here?

Comment: No - it's just a colloquial shorthand for 'to make it seem awesome'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a colloquial (and internet-idiomatic) way of speaking or writing.

> sound effect added for effect.

Is a very common expression. They have swapped out *effect* for *awesome* because it's fun. The effect they are going for is to make it *more awesome*.

Similarly I might say

> with extra bbq sauce for tasty-noms.

> with extra Seth Rogan for LOLs.

Comment: **As an aside...**
The OP expression is especially fun as it's kinda circular.

> sound effect added for awesome.

> the word awesome added for effect.

Comment: A similar idiomatic slang construction is "because [noun]"; for instance there is a youtube channel called "Because Science."